# Get Angular errors in a different language

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-material-8

If I validate an Angular Reactive form like this

```
this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  formControl: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
});
```

So the input is required.

Then if I try to submit with the input blank I receive errors like this:

```
const { errors } = this.formGroup.get('formControl');
console.log(errors);
```

I receive the following output

```
{required: true}
```

#### My question

Can I get this error in another language?

For example, could I set it to french and have the output?

```
{obligatoires: vrai}
```

#### The Why

I am trying out an approach to autogenerate error messages from validation errors.

I am doodling in this StackBlitz and would like to know if I could get this working

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-validation-errors

Comment: I think you cant do that, but you can create custom validator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The proper way to achieve this is to keep Angular output and translate it in the UI using [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) for example :

You got something like this :

```
<div>{{ 'required' | translate }}</div>
```

Comment: This is just for translation. But when we type in input then only it is throwing error. Validation must accept any text language. That we need to implement

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom component like `<custom-error>` instead of `<mat-error>` where you can use [ng2-translate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-translate) or [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) to translate the error messages. That is what we are doing in our application.

Comment: We tried to do the same, but apparently Material's mat-error only works correctly if it appears on the same level in the DOM as the <input>. Otherwise it loses its styling and attachment to the input field and you have to rebuild the styling yourself...

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom validators like suggested in comment. You can even look at the **[source code for validators](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/validators.ts)** and just modify them to your needs. Here's the customized `required` validator:

```ts
function isEmptyInputValue(value: any): boolean {
  return value == null || value.length === 0;
}

class ValidatorHelper {
 static required(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return isEmptyInputValue(control.value) ? { 'obligatoires' : 'vrai' } : null;
  }
}
```

Then use it in your form like:

```ts
selectFormControl: new FormControl(null, [ValidatorHelper.required])
```

**DEMO: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-validation-errors-8riusb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

*PS. Here we now assume that you only have one language, if you have multiple, this is not the best solution.*

Comment: yes I suppose if I could just translate those string. Maybe need to investigate i18n angular more. i would prefer to use angular i18n rather than ngx translate or any other third party package

Comment: Sure. Just wanted to throw this option out there. Source code is available, there aren't many in built validators, so this is a copy paste scenario with just changing a few lines. As said, just wanted to throw this option out there, if it's not suitable for you, maybe for someone in the future that is thinking about the same issue :) But at least you have options to choose from! But it isn't possible as far as I know, to just change the language just like that. I might be wrong, glad to see if someone can prove me wrong! :D

Comment: This answer suggests a pretty bad design. As much as possible, you should only have one language within your programs until the very end when you present the information to the user - at that point you can translate stuff. In our project, we basically extract all keys from control.errors and then translate these with a | translateError pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue some time ago. We developed a library to tackle this problem.

https://github.com/RiskChallenger/translation-validation